# I2C-controlled digital counter

Tags: i2c, counter

I need for a project an IC which should generate a digital signal with a length given by an I2C-signal, i.e. if I send the IC "50" (or something similar with the same meaning), I want to get 50 "on-off-sequences" with a given speed (via I2C, too) with a high level of 5 V. I was thinking of an counter controlled via I2C. Is there something suitable for me? Or should I approach my problem in a different way?

Comment: Never heard of it, but most MCUs should be able to ace this.

Comment: Using an MCU as an I2C slave device could be made to support this concept as Ignacio has stated but be aware that first off the MCU will really need to have an I2C peripheral block.

Comment: i2c bitbanged slave is easy to do and not very processor intensive. No built-in i2c peripheral needed. @MichaelKaras

Comment: @Passerby: What do you mean with that? Should a separate MCU do bitbanging, or the I2C-master?

Comment: Both can if you want. Bitbanging means software based implementation, instead of hardware peripheral. In your case, you would take a second microcontroller, either with or without a hardware i2c implementation, and code it to be a slave i2c device. Hundreds of examples of that can be found.

Comment: @Passerby - I2C slave bit banging is indeed relatively easy to do if that is all the processor is going to be doing. It is more of a challenge to write an arbitrary bit bang slave protocol and have the software doing a bunch of other things. Such a system needs to have the protocol carefully designed to allow the rest of the MCUs work to parceled out in bursts at the right times in step with any polling going on looking for edges on the I2C interface.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Edge Transition triggers an interrupt for the known i2c start condition, and known packet size/format. And the rest of OPs requirement is simple bit banging as well but can easily be done by a timer peripheral. OP controls the entire system, and the low complexity doesn't have any of the problems you are imagining.

Comment: If size or cost is an issue, even an 8-pin [PIC12LF1552](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001674D.pdf) (80ȼ in single quantities) has built-in I²C, along with several PIC16's in 14-pin packages starting at 90ȼ.  So no need for bit-banging.

Answer (score 2):

There is no purpose-built chip for this. However virtually any microcontroller can do this. My personal favorite is ATtiny85 which is available from local online dealers at half a dollar each and is compatible with Arduino environment.

Be careful when programming both this MCU and your host device, as you don't want communications to throw off pulse timing.

Another solution with more complicated circuitry, you can build one from a 74HCxx counter chip, a 555 timer for the pulses output as well as a clock for the counter, an I2C digital pot (setting the clock frequency and latching the number into the counter, an I2C I/O expander (setting the counter) and a few diodes.